# There is no start activity in process "*.bpel"

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl, bpel

I have one BPEL process. Even though i have a receve in the begining of the process when i compile i receve this error:

```
There is no start activity in process "*.bpel"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Consider adding some code to your question so that others can help you out.  SO is not a code writing service, so seeing that you have at least attempted encourages others to help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem in this way:

1. Add `createInstance="yes"`to the first receive activity.